# Examples of applications that use Java Message Service

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, mom

I have read some tutorials and articles about JMS, but none of these give an example of an application that can use this API. I was wondering if someone can give an example of a real world use of Java Message Service.
Thanks

Comment: What is you task or concrete purpose? This is a Q-A site, not training service.

Comment: I just want to know how this technology can be used. I have a basic understanding of how it works, but I can't think of an application that can make use of this service.

Comment: Any kind of integration, when you application or system consists of many modules that need to send and receive data between themselves. E. g. internet-banking backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some samples here:

https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/jms